# search a sentence and its combinations via full text search

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search

I'm using MyISAM engine and full text search. I have a `text` column in a table.
Suppose there is a requested sentence like this : 
**"We have two blue cars"** 
and I have these records in `text` columns.

- We have two blue cars
- we
- have
- two
- blue
- cars
- we have
- two blue
- we have two
- blue cars

... and any combinations similar to above.

I need a full text search query to return following result with **given order:**
1=> We have two blue cars 
2 => We have two blue
3 => We have two
4 => We have
5 => we
5 => have
5 => two
5 => blue
5 => cars
The order after **5** is not important so much therefore I repeated **5**, several times. I try multiple full text patterns but the order is based on `id` (primary key) column
Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I did it with this query, but I'm not sure about the performance.

```
SELECT tbl.*,
MATCH(text)
AGAINST ('
("We have two blue cars") 
("We have two blue") 
("We have two") 
("We have") 
We have two blue cars'
IN BOOLEAN MODE) as score FROM tbl where 

MATCH(text)
 AGAINST ('
("We have two blue cars") 
("We have two blue") 
("We have two") 
("We have") 
We have two blue cars
' IN BOOLEAN MODE) 
ORDER BY score DESC ;`
```

It returns my following result and take about 0.0706 seconds with 9240 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like below, it will be useful to get your desired output.

```
     Select column
     from table 
     WHERE `TEXT` LIKE '%We%' and
    `TEXT` LIKE '%have%' and
    `TEXT` LIKE '% two%' and
    'TEXT' LIKE '%blue%' and
    'TEXT' LIKE '%cars%';
```

Comment: Thank you but this is not full text search. I need to search and fetch from db as fastest as possible and it is available via full text search as far as I know.

Comment: Try reading through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search

Comment: Chetan as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/full-text-search#like Like operator has some limitations specially in term of speed.